# Trying to log date and time into sqlite3

Tags: python, date, time, sqlite, return

My goal is to take two variables, xdate and xtime and store them into an sqlite database in two separate columns using a python scripts. My code is

```
from datetime import datetime
import sqlite3 as mydb
import sys

con = mydb.connect('testTime.db')

def logTime():
   i=datetime.now()
   xdate = i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
   xtime = i.strftime('%H-%M-%S')
   return xdate, xtime
z=logTime()
```

this is where I get hung up I tried

```
try:
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO DT(Date, Time) Values (?,?)' (z[0],z[1]))
        data = cur.fetchone()
        print (data)
    con.commit()
except:
    with con:
        cur=con.cursor()
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE DT(Date, Time)')
        cur.commit()
```

I keep getting none when I try to fetch the data.

Any tips or recommended readings??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing a insert query, it's result is not having any thing to fetch. You should run a select query and then fetch the data.

> fetchone()
>
> ```
> Fetches the next row of a query result set, returning a single sequence, or None when no more data is available.
> ```

An example -

```
>>> cur.execute('INSERT INTO DT(Date, Time) Values (?,?)', (z[0],z[1]))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0353DF60>
>>> print cur.fetchone()
None
>>> cur.execute('SELECT Date, Time from DT')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0353DF60>
>>> print cur.fetchone()
(u'2016-02-25', u'12-46-16')
```